# How to display values of array in json format in table

Tags: angularjs, arrays, json

I have var customer array and I stored my response in that array. Now I need to populate the values to table, if `intrstd` present in response.

I am unable to get that .

JSON:

```
var customer = 
 [
  [
    {
      "businessuserid": 52,
      "businessusername": "Cars workshop",
      "businessusermobile": "9535000636",
      "businessusercountrycode": "91",
      "admin": true,
      "mobilevalidated": true,
      "emailvalidated": false,
      "email": "preethi@car.com",
      "upin": "000052"
    },
    {
      "businessuserid": 59,
      "businessusername": "MCF Business",
      "businessusermobile": "00",
      "businessusercountrycode": "91",
      "admin": true,
      "mobilevalidated": true,
      "emailvalidated": false,
      "email": "pavanhachholli@groupz.in",
      "upin": "000059"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "businessuserid": 44,
      "businessusername": "rk business New",
      "businessusermobile": "00",
      "businessusercountrycode": "91",
      "admin": true,
      "mobilevalidated": false,
      "emailvalidated": false,
      "email": "riteshnew@gmail.com",
      "upin": "000044"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "approved": true,
      "businessuserid": 43,
      "businessusername": "Cakey Bakes",
      "businessusermobile": "8050663763",
      "businessusercountrycode": "91",
      "admin": true,
      "mobilevalidated": true,
      "emailvalidated": false,
      "email": "preethi@groupz.com",
      "upin": "000043"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "intrsted": true,
      "attended": false,
      "businessuserid": 44,
      "businessusername": "rk business New",
      "businessusermobile": "00",
      "businessusercountrycode": "91",
      "admin": true,
      "mobilevalidated": false,
      "emailvalidated": false,
      "email": "riteshnew@gmail.com",
      "upin": "000044"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "intrsted": true,
      "attended": false,
      "businessuserid": 52,
      "businessusername": "Cars workshop",
      "businessusermobile": "9535000636",
      "businessusercountrycode": "91",
      "admin": true,
      "mobilevalidated": true,
      "emailvalidated": false,
      "email": "preethi@car.com",
      "upin": "000052"
    }
  ]
```

JS:

```
   $scope.userdetails = function(){
    for(var i=0;i<$scope.newuserlist[i].length;i++){


        for(var j=0;j<$scope.interested.length;j++){

               if($scope.interested[j].intrsted == undefined){
                        $scope.undefinedprogram = "null";
                    }
                    else if($scope.interested[j].intrsted == true){
                         $scope.users = $scope.interested[j].businessusername; 
            console.log($scope.users );
                        $scope.modalvalues.push($scope.users);
            console.log($scope.modalvalues);
                    }
        }
        }

};
```

If I am able to fetch only array values where `"intrsted":` tag is present,I will be able to populate the value in table accordingly.

Comment: You are asking question before even trying out.?

Comment: what have you tried. Did you try filtering the array for those elements where "intrsted": property is present.

Comment: What did your mean by "intrsted" ?

Comment: Yes, it is possible using filters. google and try on your own if stuck then ask

Comment: Hi I tried out. I given JS file above. Please have a look

Comment: You are trying to do the filtering yourself. Let angularjs do it for you. Just bind to the data and filter. I suggest you watch some basic angularjs tutorials.

Comment: I am just a beginner anyway thanks for your ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming angularjs since you have the angularjs tag. You could use [ng-repeat](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) to loop through your data, and use a [filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) to display only the relevant records:

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in your.controller.your.data | filter: { intrsted: true }">
        <td>{{item.businessusername}}</td>
        ...
    </tr>
</table>
```

But really, this is the most basic angularjs application possible. You can get this information from any beginner tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

try this may help you

```
var tbl=$("<table/>").attr("id","mytable");
    $("#div1").append(tbl);
    for(var i=0;i<customer.length;i++)
      {
         var tr="<tr>";
         var td1="<td>"+customer[i]["id"]+"</td>";
         var td2="<td>"+customer[i]["businessusername"]+"</td>";
         var td3="<td>"+customer[i]["businessusermobile"]+"</td></tr>";
         $("#mytable").append(tr+td1+td2+td3); 

    }
```